# extjs 5 associations between two models

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

There are two model and connected stores: user and orders in frontend. There are two api calls in backend: getOrder(orderId), and getOrders().
In 'order store' I specified proxy settings for getOrders(). In 'order model' I specified proxy for getOrder(orderId).
When I call user's load method to get associated orders in this case uses model's proxy. Why not use proxy from store? Why it is not using.

P.S.: relation between user and order is descripted in backend and depends on authentication params of user.

User model code

```js
Ext.define('Dev.models.User', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  requires: ['Dev.stores.Orders'],
  fields: [
    //data
    {name: "name", type: "string"},
    {name: "userId", type: "string"}
  ],

  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/tcc/getmember',
    idParam: 'memberId',

    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      idProperty : 'memberId'
    }
  },

  hasMany: {
    model: 'Dev.models.Order',
    name: 'orders',
    storeConfig: {
      type: 'orders',
      filters: []
    }
  }
});
```

Order model code

```js
Ext.define('Dev.models.Order', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  idProperty : 'orderId',
  fields: [
    {name: "orderId",   type: "string"},
    {name: "title",     type: "string"},
    {name: "createMember",     type: "string"}
  ],

  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
      create: '/tcc/setorder',
      read: '/tcc/getorder',
      update: '/tcc/setorder',
      destroy: '/tcc/deleteorder'
    },
    idParam : 'orderId',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      idProperty : 'orderId'
    }
  },

  belongsTo: {
    model: "Dev.models.User",
    name: 'user',
    getterName: 'getUser',
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    primaryKey: 'createMember'
  }
});
```

Order store code

```js
Ext.define('Dev.stores.Orders', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'Dev.models.Order',
alias: 'store.orders',
proxy : {
  type : 'ajax',
    api: {
      create: '/tcc/setorder',
      read: '/tcc/getorders',
      update: '/tcc/setorder',
      destroy: '/tcc/deleteorder'
    },
    reader : {
      root: 'orders',
      type : 'json',
      idProperty : 'orderId'
    }
  }
});
```

Sample of usage

```js
function doMemberOne(userId) {
  Dev.models.User.load(userId, {
    success: function(record, operation) {
      console.log("User model was loaded successfully");
      doOrders(record.orders());
    },
    failure: function(record, operation) {
      console.log("User model was loaded unsuccessfully");
    }
  });
}

function doOrders(orderStore) {
  orderStore.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
      if (success) {
        console.log("Orders was loaded successfully");
      } else {
        console.log("Orders was loaded unsuccessfully");
      }
    }
  });
}

Ext.onReady(function() {
  Dev.Authentication.login("admin", "adminpass", "adminorg");
  Dev.Authentication.on('login', function(resp) {
    console.log("Login is successful.");
    doMemberOne(resp.accountid);
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you know it does not work? I have tried to reproduce your test case in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7p9), and it is working as expected... It is indeed the proxy configured in the `storeConfig`'s store that is used, and not the model's default one.

Comment: In your sample you use "field" property in hasMany config. I can not do same things  in my code (see PS part above). I haven't any fields for connect this models. In extjs 4.2 I can do it.

Comment: The `field` option is not relevant; I have removed it from [my example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7p9) and I still observe the same result. That is, the proxy that is used to load the relation is -- as expected -- the proxy of the store from the `storeConfig` option. Which brings me back to my original question: how do you know that it does not work? Or better yet, can you demonstrate your issue in a fiddle?

Comment: If the code you had was exactly what was broken, the missing `}` at the end of the fields property definition in the User model may have been at fault, not sure though, I just saw the omission and corrected it.